# Remove the rectangle drawn on the chart plotly within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I can draw a triangle with one click, I can change its shape, but how do I delete this rectangle?

```
library(plotly)

x <- 1:50
y <- rnorm(50)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig <- config(fig,modeBarButtonsToAdd = list('drawrect'))

fig
```

[image]

Comment: "Refresh" the viewer?

Comment: @zx8754
Hmm, it works)) but what if the graph is shiny?
I thought that there is some kind of general solution, something like a button that will work regardless of the display environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the button *eraseshape*:

```r
config(fig,modeBarButtonsToAdd = list('drawrect', 'eraseshape'))
```

then select the rectangle and click this button.